# Keyerror, не может найти элемент в ответе json

Tags: python, json, парсер

Пытаюсь спарсить токен сессии, но не может найти элемент в ответе

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(logonBody))

dataresponse = response.text

# save session token

jsonresponse = json.loads(dataresponse)
print(jsonresponse['session'])
```

jsonresponse:

```
 {'result': {'employee_id': 1,
                'privilege': -1,
'session':'7e07b3e2dd8cea22a9409024f512a7203a00d3b8dbeefa2a22269afdfcab2e3a'}}
```

Выдает ошибку

```
 print(jsonresponse['session']) 
KeyError: 'session'
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: в jsonresponse вижу только ключ "result". Решить проблему просто - обратиться к нужному ключу, который находится во вложенном словаре.

Comment: `print(jsonresponse['result']['session'])`

Comment: спасибо за ответы, помогло!